# What code highlighting libs are there for Java?

Tags: java, syntax-highlighting, codehighlighter

I'd like them to be easy to bundle, with few dependencies and easy to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you want to highlight Java code or use a Java lib to highlight some other code?

I use these two: https://jhighlight.dev.java.net/ (server-side) for xml and http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/ (js lib) for other stuff. The latter has something called 'brushes' which are "pluggable" .js for several langauges. If you are doing simple highlighting, I recommend the ,js approach.

Comment: Apparently the syntaxhighligher js library is now located at http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Comment: If you want server side simple highlighting, there are Java ports of syntaxhighlighter and of prettify. Have a look at my approach https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-prettify/AANTzgRe81k

Comment: The first link is broken.

Comment: There is https://github.com/codelibs/jhighlight. Don't know for sure that it's the same project as https://jhighlight.dev.java.net/.

Answer (score 2):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jintilla/

http://syntax.jedit.org/

Answer (score 2):

http://tohtml.com/ this one is good.

Comment: +1, good to know, but this is for the online syntax highlight.

Answer (score 2):

A little update, as we were recently looking for highlighting lib, we found the very good Jygments : http://code.google.com/p/jygments/ .

Available for Ant/Maven/SBT projects throught threecrickets repo, it's a Java port of Pygments ( http://pygments.org ), working for several major languages.

Answer (score 1):

RSyntaxTextArea is worked for me[Here](http://bobbylight.github.io/RSyntaxTextArea/)

```
        RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea();
        textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_JAVA);
        textArea.setCodeFoldingEnabled(true);
        RTextScrollPane rs = new RTextScrollPane(textArea);
```