# Where can I find a syntax highlighting library for Java?

Tags: java, editor, syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a source-code editor in Java (for Java source code), and I'd like to add simple syntax highlighting (distinctive coloring for keywords would suffice). Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if I'd even use the "almost" in the phrase "almost incomprehensible".

Comment: Tried to improve this in a way that supports mmyers' answer.

Comment: I just went with the "code for syntax highlighting" part and ignored the rest of it. I have no idea if that's what he's looking for or not.

Comment: Question about Java syntax-highlighting libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221570/what-code-highlighting-libs-are-there-for-java

Comment: Yeah. Funny thing is, if you type that into google, you get a bunch of results. One of them is this dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221570/what-code-highlighting-libs-are-there-for-java.

Comment: @Shog9: editing the question to fit an answer?  Is that kosher?

Comment: Voted down, you shouldn't use SO for questions that are easily answered after a google search. Also it was almost impossible to read

Comment: @MarcG: Not sure where you got that opinion, but you are rather wrong. That is /exactly/ what SO is for.

Comment: @Shog9 good rewrite!.  The original was terrible...

Comment: I had voted it down previously because in its original form the question was utterly incomprehensible. And Marc G is completely wrong on his assertion that SO isn't for simple questions. Please refer to the newest podcast for Jeff & Joel's take.

Comment: OK, easy out, it's obvious that we're not dealing with a native english speaker.
@MarcG where you got that impression? This is completely wrong. @Erich Mirabal this (the edited version) is a real and valid question.

Comment: The question isn't clear about whether you want to write you're own syntax highlighting stuff or just using a lib. That's why you're getting quite different answers...

Comment: @ktulur: The answers look fine for what they are asking.

Comment: Interesting that the 4 libraries mentioned in the other "Java syntax-highlighting lib" question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221570/what-code-highlighting-libs-are-there-for-java] are totally different than the options so far mentioned here.

Comment: @Rich B : before the rewrite it was impossible to read an the meaning of the question changed. I thought it was something different, so my bad. I undid my down vote

Comment: (The way I understood it was "how do I put syntax highlighting in my IDE" or something like that.)

Comment: @MarcG: It really makes no difference how you understood it. Your original statement is flat out wrong.

Comment: @McWafflestix: There's some disagreement, but i hold that it is entirely appropriate in cases where the question is ambiguous. Remember, the goal is to create value for others to find and use in the future: therefore, a question should be specific and have specific answers; otherwise, it won't be found and re-used. I have no problem with editing questions to fit this vision - if i guess wrong, the original author can always ask another question, taking care to be more specific the second time around...

Comment: @Rich B: Ok I suppose you know better

Comment: Wow, you guys clearly have no understanding of what he said. He said he wants to add syntax-highlighting to his text-editor, so simply suggesting him a method or some library to do it would have sufficed.

Answer (score 22):

Something like [`JSyntaxPane`](http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/), perhaps?

> A very simple to use and extend JEditorKit that supports few languages. The main goal is to make it easy to have nice looking Java Swing Editors with support for Syntax Highlighting.

Comment: This is not maintained anymore. Use [`RSyntaxTextArea`](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea) for new projects.

Answer (score 14):

What about [RSyntaxTextArea](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea)? It uses a [modified BSD license](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea/blob/master/src/main/dist/RSyntaxTextArea.License.txt).

Comment: So bad? I'm using it in a project and I think it's great. Besides, If you want to code your own stuff you can study it as it's opensource.

Comment: Tried and looks great, like the features like code folding. It does not support python, it is a pity.

Comment: sorry it support python. its website mislead me, and their applet too.

Comment: This should be upvoted more often and accepted as an answer - it's afaik the only library that is still being maintained.

Answer (score 4):

You first should think about using a common parser to create an AST (abstract syntax tree) from the sources. There are some tools around, first I find googling the internet was [javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/). It looks like this parser also records line numbers and columns, so the AST from javaparser can be a nice model for the editor.

Just process the tree, define colors for the AST node types and print it.

Answer (score 2):

Might want to look at an existing editor (Notepad++ for example - http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) and see how user-defined syntax highlighting is done (oneo of the plugins to check - Gmod 10 Lua Syntax Highlighter).  I'd wager that the Java (and other languages) are done similarly...

Answer (score 1):

You should check Google's [prettify.js](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) out. Some pretty neat tricks in there, and you might get a more robust feel for syntax highlighting.

Comment: @ktulur: Did you actually look at it? It does syntax highlighting for many languages including Java. This will be a great way to learn how to write a syntax highlighting algorithm. Specifically one that can support multiple languages.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I was thinking about using an existing component ,not about writing your own stuff. That's why when I've read ".js" I was like "wtf?"

Comment: Sometimes it is nice to teach people to learn, not just reuse.

Comment: Yep sometimes, but generally, isn't it better reuse? I think that in that way you can spend your time in your own original stuff.

Comment: If that were the case, why on earth would he be writing a Java editor in the first place?

Comment: There is a Java port of `prettify.js`; it is `java-prettify`:  https://code.google.com/p/java-prettify/

Answer (score -4):

http://www.neathighlighter.com/ is a good JavaScript highlighter