# Answer editor like this site's?

Tags: html, editor, syntax-highlighting, forum, code-snippets

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to how to 
implement the editor that opens up when I try to post an answer or type a new question ?

Also when displaying the replies how is the feature with syntax highlighting for the code snippets implemented ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Javascript based editor is a heavily modified version of [WMD Markdown Editor](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/).

Moving on to your second question. What server side language are you using? For example, in PHP Geshi is a popluar syntax highlighter. Although I personally have not worked with it.

Comment: I'm using Java(JSP and Servlets) on the server side. How do I integrate such a javascript based editor and the syntax highlighter?

Comment: @armageddon11: I have no experience with Java. But, have a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864688/where-can-i-find-a-syntax-highlighting-library-for-java

Comment: No that does not solve my problem. Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Editor control that comes with AJAX Control Tool kit