# How to add part of code to pdf in itext 5

Tags: java, itext

I'm looking for a way to add a formatted code to a pdf file. Now I use iText 5.5.10 to generating pdf. I need to recognize syntax and color it.

iText library can something like this, or can with another library?
Maybe I must change the library to generating pdf?

Answer (score 1):

I had to flag your question as off topic because of

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

However, I still have a (partial) answer for you. What you are looking for, is called a Syntax Highlighter. A very popular and well-known one is GeSHi (General Syntax Highlighter), but that lives in the PHP world. You are looking for a "GeSHi for Java". I personally don't know any, but I suggest that you google for "java syntax highlighter library". One of the search results is JHighlight, with description *"JHighlight is an embeddable pure Java syntax highlighting library that supports Java, HTML, XHTML, XML and LZX languages and outputs to XHTML."* I haven't tried it myself. There are others, please continue your research.

Your question essentially boils down to a partial duplicate of [Where can I find a syntax highlighting library for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864688/where-can-i-find-a-syntax-highlighting-library-for-java)

What you do then, is:

- start with source code as plain text
- use a syntax highlighter library to convert it to formatted (X)HTML
- use iText to convert the (X)HTML to PDF

I *strongly recommend* that you do not use iText 5, but use **iText 7 + pdfHTML** add-on instead. The HTML-to-PDF functionality is much richer in iText 7, and iText 5 is end-of-life (only security updates for customers).