# Syntax Highlighter for Java

Tags: java, syntax-highlighting, geshi

As you know there is a Syntax highlighter for PHP called [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) which supports a great number of Programming Languages or Code formats.

However, I couldn't find such a library for Java which supports programming languages that I need (ADA, ASP, BNF, Bash, Brainfuck, C, C++, C#, CSS, Cobol, ColdFusion, D, Fortran, Haskell, HTML, INI (Config), Java, JavaScript, Lisp, Make, Objective C, PASCAL, Perl, PHP, PLSQL, Prolog, Python, Ruby, Scheme, SQL, VB.NET, Verilog, VHDL, Visual Basic, XML.)

Do you know one or should I prefer inefficient way which is retrieving the highlighted code from a remote PHP server via http transaction? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean, 'written in Java'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two related questions:

[What code highlighting libs are there for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221570/what-code-highlighting-libs-are-there-for-java)
[Where can I find a syntax highlighting library for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864688/where-can-i-find-a-syntax-highlighting-library-for-java)

And one library I found: http://colorer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: All these have a small number of languages. :( Thanks anyway.

Comment: the last link claims: Colorer-take5 supports more than hundred programming languages, scripts and markups. I haven't checked though

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [JHighlighter](https://jhighlight.dev.java.net/) or [jEdit Syntax Package](http://syntax.jedit.org/). All mentioned languages aren't supported out of the box. However, you have the sources, so I guess it should be possible to add language support.

Not a direct answer but, if client-side syntax highlighting is an option, the [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/) library from Alex Gorbatchev is an awesome javascript library, supports lots of [languages](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/09/list-of-brushes-syntaxhighligher/) and is highly [extensible](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter:Brushes:Custom).

Comment: I prefer the SyntaxHighlighter - works great, keeps the work out of server,  lowers the traffic, leaves the code intact for search engines.

Comment: @Ondra I totally agree with you. Actually, SyntaxHighlighter is so great that it became a kind of de facto standard on the web nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) through Jython. Won't be as fast as a Java solution, but much faster than interacting with a remote server.

Barring that, you could run Geshi locally and pipe source code through it, that would also beat an HTTP round trip.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is possible to run [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) from Java: [GeSHi4J](https://github.com/collegeman/geshi4j) it seems to be a wrapper that run the PHP library on the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

There is a port of [prettify.js](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) for Java: [java-prettify](https://code.google.com/p/java-prettify/).

It can be used to produce HTML (computed in Java), as I discussed here:
[Use the java-prettify parser to create HTML](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-prettify/AANTzgRe81k)

Answer (score 0):

[jedit](http://jedit.org) is a text editor with syntax highlighting support for some 170+ languages via "modes". It also allows you to specify your own syntaxes. You can use the StandaloneTextArea component in your own application as follows:

- Extract source (eg: jedit4.3source.tar.bz2 to d:\source\jedit)
- Use ant to copy all the textarea files to ..\textarea eg:

  D:\Source\jedit\jEdit> ant prepare-textArea
- However, it misses the file BufferUndoListener.java. Copy this manually by executing

  D:\Source\jedit\jEdit> copy org\gjt\sp\jedit\buffer\BufferUndoListener.java ..\textarea\src\org\gjt\sp\jedit\buffer\
- In Eclipse create a Java Project from existing source in the directory D:\Source\jedit\textarea
- Navigate to org.gjt.sp.jedit.textarea.StandaloneTextArea.java
- Change the line

> ```
> mode.setProperty("file","modes/xml.xml");
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> mode.setProperty("file","src/modes/xml.xml");
> ```

- Run. Copy and paste an XML into the editor and see the syntax highlighting is working.