# How to change all of 'a' characters is string and show in JEditorPane or JTextArea?

Tags: java, c++, qt5, jtextarea, jeditorpane

I want to create simple TextEditor program that find all 'a' characters in String and change color to red.I can find 'a' characters so i just need to change color.If it is not possible in java , can i do this in c++(QT Lib.)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JEditorPane set foreground color for different words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948148/jeditorpane-set-foreground-color-for-different-words)

Comment: Thank you,it's good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JEditor Pane in Java support HTML and CSS. So put html and css code for anything you want like changing color, bold and italic etc.

```
pane  = new JEditorPane();
pane.setContentType("text/html");
```

you can write html and inline css directly.

For advance level you can also use HTMLEditorKit class for adding css.

```
HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
jEditorPane.setEditorKit(kit);
StyleSheet styleSheet = kit.getStyleSheet();
styleSheet.addRule("body {color:#000; font-family:times; margin: 4px; }");
styleSheet.addRule("h1 {color: blue;}");
styleSheet.addRule("h2 {color: #ff0000;}");
styleSheet.addRule("pre {font : 10px monaco; color : black; background-color : #fafafa; }");
```

I hope I helped you.