# Colour specific words in JEditorPane depending on string tags

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I am working on a GUI for my game, which previously purely ran as text in the terminal. The GUI interfaces with the engine by simply taking the text (which would otherwise just be printed to standard output) and giving it to fields across the window.

The way colours are handled in the terminal interface is by using ANSI escape sequences. I have a method, CFG.colour(), which takes in the string to be coloured and colours it. It does this by appending the string to the ANSI sequence for the colour, and then appending the reset sequence to the end of that.

I would like to keep this backwards compatible, so there is still an option to run in the terminal if desired. I thought I could do this by using HTML, as I know that can be displayed with a JEditorPane. My thinking was, when the program is started in the terminal, the strings which store the colour tags would be set to their ANSI versions, and if the program is started in graphical mode, the colour tags would be set to HTML tags. I couldn't get this to work, but I am not very experienced with HTML.

More concisely, what I want are some Strings 'colourStart' and 'end', such that when I display

```
colourStart + "Hello" + end
```

in the JEditorPane, it will show "Hello", coloured with whatever is colour is specified by colourStart.

I know exactly what I'm saying is not possible, but that is the ideal scenario, so I figured by explaining that it would make it easier to find a solution that works for me.

Comment: If you want to append text to the `JEditorPane`, I wouldn't use `HTML`, as `HTML` has a defined start and end.  Instead, I might consider making use of `JTextPane` and a `StyledDocument` instead, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948148/jeditorpane-set-foreground-color-for-different-words/18948340#18948340)

Comment: I would also approach the problem differently.  You're going have to translate the information for the GUI differently then you would for the console, so I'd let go of the idea of "re-using" the workflow.  Instead, I might consider defining a "translation" or "transformation" layering which can be plugged in based on the desired destination (console/GUI)

Comment: I'm not actually appending to the JEditorPane itself. I reason why I want to reuse the workflow is because the colour tags are appended usually within the toString() of the object. What I'm really doing is stuff like 'mapDisplay.setText(map)', where mapDisplay is the JEditorPane and map is the map object. In the console, map would instead just be printed.

Comment: Sure, but you have two different output concepts, you're going to need to modify the transformation layer to support them - unless you really want to spend a whole lot of time building your own `StyledDocument` which can handle ansi codes ... but really, you'd just be writing a transformation layer, just in different place. I'd still be tempted to use `JTextPane` and `JEditorPane` is just another layer of complexity. Remember, you also need to set the `contentType` of the `JEditorPane`, as it may not automagically recognise the text

Comment: I may be misremembering, but I think I only used JEditorPane because it can display HTML, and I saw potential in the future for using that for the colour, so I may see if I can switch over to JTextPane without any issues, like you mentioned. Can you elaborate about the transformation layer? thanks.

Comment: Ultimately, it will depend on what you want to achieve.  Yes, `JEditorPane` can display `HTML` based text, so if your "transformation" layer can generate `HTML` text, then that should be suitable. I'd consider if you want to "append" text to it, as that's not something it would really support.  It might be the easier option. *"I have a method, CFG.colour(), which takes in the string to be coloured and colours it"* - you seem to have a "transformation" layer already, what I might do is create a `interface` can convert the input to `String`, transformed accordingly (ie ansi or html)

Comment: I'd then have two implementations, one for ansi and html transformation and then I'd just have a setup phase which would instantiate the correct one and the rest of the code should continue to work as expected

Comment: Okay, I think I understand you now. Yes, I already have this transformation layer in place. My question was really what the Strings should be to have the CFG.colour() format correctly for HTML. What I have in CFG.colour() is `colourTag + input + resetTag`, and when running in the terminal, the values for the strings `colourTag` and `resetTag` are set to their ANSI equivalents. What I want is to simply change the value of `colourTag` and `resetTag` to some HTML equivalent when running in GUI. Hope that cleared things up?

Comment: No, I would create a "new" transformation layer to handle the html translations.  I mean, what is `colorTag` <- what information does it carry. For example, in html, color is typically controlled by the `style` tag, ie `<span style="color:blue;">Text</span>` <- You'd need to translate your `colourTag` to support this

Comment: wouldn't it be possible then to have `colourTag = "<span style=\"color:xxx;\">"` and then `endTag = "</span>`, having the 'xxx' be replaced depending on the colour desired?

Comment: For me - I'd be aiming to pass it the "text" and "formatting" information to the transformer and have it return a completed `String` - then it's as simple, as you say, to call `setText` - all the work is done in the transformation layer.  When you want to output to the console, you'd have the same workflow, just with a different transformer - but that's me.

Comment: I understand and I think you make very good points. I attempted what I described (I actually attempted it before I posted this question, but I couldn't get it to work, so I thought it was impossible), and the colour works, however, I cannot get newlines to display properly. I am using String.replace("\n", "<br>"), however, this is making it ad a line break after what appears to be every character. Do you have any explaination for that?

Comment: NVM, I got it working (I'm not sure how...). Thanks for all your help and feedback :D