# generate SQL query to HTML with Java

Tags: java, qsqlquery

I have a Java server and I have a String of a SQL query.
I want to get a string of the query in HTML (with colors like prettifier).

In the client side I used `prettyPrintOne` in angular, but I need to get it from the server side now.

Comment: Your question is not very clear but if you have a SQL string available then use any api like https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html or http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-to-Pretty-Print-Minify-Scripts.html

Comment: thanks for the quick answer.. but i need to implement this with java

Comment: Where do you print it in java side? In console or Java Swing pane??

Comment: i need to get the html as a string in java

Comment: i am adding it to a mail body (javamail)

Comment: In javamail your message contains HTML markup. Send email in html format with String as html   // message contains HTML markups
        String message = "<i>Greetings!</i><br>";
        message += "<b>Wish you a nice day!</b><br>";
        message += "<font color=red>Duke</font>";
 
        HtmlEmailSender mailer = new HtmlEmailSender();
 
        try {
            mailer.sendHtmlEmail(host, port, mailFrom, password, mailTo,

Comment: i know, but i am asking how can i get from a sql string -> a string of the generate html (to make it look nice) ?

Comment: You should be able to post the generated HTML (prettified) as a normal form parameter and consume it from the Java side as a normal HTTP request parameter (with the framework or tool of your choice). Do you already have a Java server? If yes, what framework are you using to handle HTTP requests?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/1853419/1737819

Comment: i think i didn't explain my self good enough. lets say that i need to create a java function that gets a String input : (the sql query) and i need it to return the html of this query in nice colors like a beautifier...