# How can I use / implement SyntaxHighlighting and autocompletition [Java | Android]

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting

currently I'm working on an app in which I have a small IDE. Now I need code-completion and syntax-highlighting. How can I realize something?

Does somebody has any idea? My first approach was an XML file from which the syntax is matched. But this would be very costly.

A corresponding API I have not found. Only "Programmr" provides an API for Web. But nor for Android / Java.

Henrik

Edit: It's not a duplicate of [What code highlighting libs are there for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221570/what-code-highlighting-libs-are-there-for-java). There are Libs for Highlighing Java in other langueages. I need a lib for Highlighing Java-Code in an self written IDE (written with Java for Android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What code highlighting libs are there for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221570/what-code-highlighting-libs-are-there-for-java)

Comment: No it isn't, I've edited the post above.