# JTextArea - autoformat like netbeans ide

Tags: java, swing, formatting, jtextarea

i'm working in java, i'm developing a programming language and i'm building the ide for it. the problem is that i'd like to have a textArea like netbeans ide's one, with formatted and colored text. for example i'd like to have a textarea where reserved words are blue, numbers are purple and function names are bold, how is it possible without losing efficiency while typing?

Comment: You probably want to use a [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) rather than a JTextArea.  As for efficiency, you may have noticed that existing IDEs have pretty heavy CPU usage;  I doubt that can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain libraries allow you to create special text areas for this exact purpose. The most popular `textArea` is the [RSyntaxTextArea](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea)

Two other related questions which may help:

[What code highlighting libs are there for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221570/what-code-highlighting-libs-are-there-for-java)

[Where can I find a syntax highlighting library for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864688/where-can-i-find-a-syntax-highlighting-library-for-java)